# How can I get correct scoreboard in 'Pong' by using pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pong

How can I get correct scoreboard in 'Pong' by using pygame? I tried many times but the scoreboard only shows me 0 and 1.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
# Initialize pygame
    pygame.init()

    # Set window size and title, and frame delay
    surfaceSize = (500, 400)  # example window size
    windowTitle = 'Pong'  # Window title is called 'Pong'
    frameDelay = 0.02  # smaller is faster game

    # Create the window
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode(surfaceSize, 0, 0)
    pygame.display.set_caption(windowTitle)

    # create and initialize objects
    gameOver = False
    # Set center
    center = [250, 200]
    # Ball/Score/Paddle color
    color = pygame.Color('white')
    # Set ball radius to 5
    ball_radius = 5
    # Set speed to [4, 1]
    ball_speed = [4, 1]
    # Set the size of the left paddle
    left_paddle = pygame.Rect(90, 180, 10, 40)
    # Set the size of the right paddle
    right_paddle = pygame.Rect(410, 180, 10, 40)
    # Set left score to 0
    left_score = 0
    # Set right score to 0
    right_score = 0


    # Draw the small ball
    pygame.draw.circle(surface, color, center, ball_radius, 0)
    # Draw the left paddle
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, left_paddle)
    # Draw the right paddle
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, right_paddle)


    # Refresh the display
    pygame.display.update()

    # Loop forever
    while True:
        # Check event
        event = pygame.event.poll()
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        # Handle additional events

        # Update and draw objects for the next frame
        gameOver = update(center,surface,ball_speed,color,ball_radius,
            left_paddle,right_paddle)

        # Refresh the display
        pygame.display.update()

        # Set the frame speed by pausing between frames
        time.sleep(frameDelay)

def update(center,surface,ball_speed,color,ball_radius,
            left_paddle,right_paddle):
    # Check if the game is over. If so, end the game and
    # return True. Otherwise, update the game objects, draw
    # them, and return False.
    # This is an example update function - replace it.
    # - center is a list containing the x and y int coords
    # of the center of a circle
    # - surface is the pygame.Surface object for the window
    if False: # check if the game is over
        return True
    else: # continue the game
        # Erase the old one
        bgColor = pygame.Color('black')
        surface.fill(bgColor)

        # Move
        moveDot(surface,center, ball_speed,ball_radius,right_paddle,left_paddle)
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, color, center, ball_radius)
        paddles(surface, color, left_paddle, right_paddle)
        drawScore(surface,center,ball_radius,right_score, left_score)
        return False

def moveDot(surface,center, ball_speed,ball_radius,right_paddle,left_paddle):
    size = surface.get_size()
    for coord in range(0, 2):
        center[coord] = center[coord] + ball_speed[coord]
        # Left edge or the top edge
        if center[coord] < ball_radius:
            ball_speed[coord] = -ball_speed[coord]
        # Right edge or the bottom edge
        if center[coord] + ball_radius > size[coord]:
            ball_speed[coord] = -ball_speed[coord]
        # Left paddle bounce and go through
        if left_paddle.collidepoint(center) and ball_speed[0] < 0:
            ball_speed[0] = -ball_speed[0]
        # Right paddle bounce and go through
        if right_paddle.collidepoint(center) and ball_speed[0] > 0:
            ball_speed[0] = -ball_speed[0]

def paddles(surface,color,left_paddle,right_paddle):
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, left_paddle)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, right_paddle)
```

**The problem is here**

```
def drawScore(surface,center,ball_radius,right_score,left_score):
    fgColor = pygame.Color('white')
    bgColor = pygame.Color('black')
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,80,True)
    left_location = (0,0)
    right_location = (465,0)    
    size = surface.get_size()
    if center[0] < ball_radius:
        right_score = right_score + 1    
    right_textSurface = font.render(str(right_score),True,fgColor,bgColor)
    surface.blit(right_textSurface,right_location)        
    if center[0] > size[0] - ball_radius:    
        left_score = left_score + 1    
    left_textSurface = font.render(str(left_score),True,fgColor,bgColor)
    surface.blit(left_textSurface,left_location)

main()
```

Comment: Are you sure your code snippet is _minimal_, as defined in [MCVE]?

Comment: Or at least, copy/pastable from here to IDE and runnable. I've suggested an edit to atleast make a full c/p compilable.

Comment: You can copy and paste those snippets to Wing IDE, I just don't want my code looks so long

Comment: but the code is looooooooong..its easier to help someone if you can quickly copy and paste it into an IDE and run it without errors to debug the problem - just a tip for posting future questions

Comment: I think the problem is at the very bottom of the code

Comment: Forget drawing the scores, can you print the scores to the console when a point is made? Are they correct?

Comment: I tried this way to debug my code. It does show my print thing on the Python  Shell. However, the score numbers just change from 0 to 1, and reset the score numbers and do the above again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the parameters, and not the actual game score

```
def drawScore(...,right_score,left_score): # given here
    ... 
    if center[0] < ball_radius:
        right_score = right_score + 1    # updated, but only locally
    ...  
    if center[0] > size[0] - ball_radius:    
        left_score = left_score + 1     # updated, but only locally
    ...
```

Those new values are not kept when the method is called again, and so you only see 0 or 1.

---

If you'd like to store state of your game, declare those variables outside of the local scope.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

left_score = 0
right_score = 0

def main():
    ...
    # remove score definition here
```

And so you then don't need to pass those scores around as parameters,

```
def drawScore(...): # remove the scores
    global left_score, right_score
    ... 
    if center[0] < ball_radius:
        right_score = right_score + 1  # accessed from global scope  
    ...  
    if center[0] > size[0] - ball_radius:    
        left_score = left_score + 1    # accessed from global scope
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but my code will doesn't run. I follow your way to change my code, and the Wing IDE shows me the error: local variable 'right_score' referenced before assignment

Comment: @Steven I think I forgot the `global` line. I have updated the answer